# How to attachment pdf with base64_encode in codeiginter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My pdf file attachment was corrupted.

Here's my code:

```
$buffer = chunk_split(base64_decode($row->arquivo));
$name = $row->nome_arquivo;
$extensao = $row->extensao;
$this->email->attach($buffer, 'attachment', $name, $extensao);
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: Could you please provide some more information on the issue you are having. What have you tried? What topics have you used when researching fixes (i.e. what have you Googled, etc)? Please also consider taking a look at the following article on [how to ask questions on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to ensure that community members can help you in the most efficient manner.

Answer (score 0):

try this  :

```
$type = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$base64 = 'data:application/pdf/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```